# Tenho uma rede neural e agora?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redes-neurais

Ola, fiz uma rede neural assistindo uma video aula sobre, o codigo e bem simples mas, funcional. E aberto um arquivo csv, separasse os dados e e feito o treino, logo apos e feito o teste e e mostrado o resultado.
Otimo, nao ha maneira de pegar isso ja treinado e executa-lo?? Pois do jeito que esta sempre ira ser feito o treinamento.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

arquivo = pd.read_csv("/Users/marlorodrigues/wine_dataset.csv")

arquivo.head()

arquivo['style'] = arquivo['style'].replace('red', 0)
arquivo['style'] = arquivo['style'].replace('white', 1)

y = arquivo['style']
x = arquivo.drop('style', axis = 1)

x_treino, x_teste, y_treino, y_teste = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3)

modelo = ExtraTreesClassifier()
modelo.fit(x_treino, y_treino)

resultado = modelo.score(x_teste, y_teste)
# print("Acuracia da Rede Neural #1 --->> ", resultado)

print(y_teste[334:339])`

previsoes = modelo.predict(x_teste[334:339])
print(previsoes)
```

Comment: Eu admirei a paciência de colocar o ` em cada linha do seu código.

Comment: No começo da pergunta diz: "fiz uma rede neural", além da tag "redes-neurais" e do título, mas no código tem um modelo `ExtraTreesClassifier`. A pergunta é como salvar uma Rede Neural ou um modelo do sklearn?

Comment: @AlexCiuffa - o modelo ExtraTreesClassifier nao e considerado uma maneira de se fazer uma rede neural??

Comment: @CypherPotato kkkkkkkkkk tentei copiar o codigo inteiro, mas nao deu, entao fui linha por linha

Comment: @ColonoPooper, não! ExtraTreesClassifier é um algoritmo baseado em um conjunto de árvores de decisão. Ele pode ser utilizado para seleção de features (entradas). As features escolhidas podem ser utilizadas para um outro modelo, como uma rede neural, mas são modelos diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Uma vez treinado seu modelo, é possível salvá-lo com o módulo [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Para salvar um `modelo` já treinado, basta fazer:

```
import pickle

filename = 'modelo_final.pkl'
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:  
    pickle.dump(modelo, file)
```

Depois, para carregar:

```
import pickle

filename = 'modelo_final.pkl'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:  
    modelo_carregado = pickle.load(file)
```

E ai é só usar o modelo normalmente, como por exemplo `modelo_carregado.score(x_teste, y_teste)`.